# how to sort a datatable frame in descending order

Tags: python, datatable

I'm trying to apply a sort on one field(total product ratings per each country) in a Frame, and here ascending is worked out, all the products are displayed in an ascending order

I have looked for it(sort options) in documentation, however its info is not written down/available.

a[:,:,sort("totals")]

is there any way to do a descending sort on this field?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to sort a column in descending order, you can put a `-` sign in front of that column. This works both for numeric and for string columns. For example:

```py
>>> import datatable as dt
>>> from datatable import f, sort
>>> A = dt.Frame(product=["apples", "spam", "goo", "bobcat", "gold"], 
                 totals=[5.4, 2.777, 0.1, 2.9, 11.1])
>>> A[:, :, sort(-f.totals)]
    product  totals
--  -------  ------
 0  gold     11.1  
 1  apples    5.4  
 2  bobcat    2.9  
 3  spam      2.777
 4  goo       0.1  

[5 rows x 2 columns]
>>> A[:, :, sort(-f.product)]
    product  totals
--  -------  ------
 0  spam      2.777
 1  goo       0.1  
 2  gold     11.1  
 3  bobcat    2.9  
 4  apples    5.4  

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```